# Importing value through data loader for a lookup field

Tags: lookup, data-loader

I have account lookup field on a custom object. I want to import records through CSV file using data loader, but this file only have Account name, not ID. How can I import this file in salesforce? As I believe entering Account Id in each record is very long process.

Answer (score 2):

We used to do a vlookup in excel and get Salesforce record Ids of parent, prepare the excel sheet and use dataloader to import.

But I think Dataloader.io provides a functionality out of box - [Using Import Lookups](https://dataloader.io/using-import-lookups)

You may try any of these options.